# My while loop does not quit python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, pygame

```
done=False

while not done:
    for level in range(1,13):
       Code...
        while running:
            Code.....

            #10 - Win/Lose check

            if healthvalue<=0:
                done=True
                running=0
                exitcode=0
                print "aaa"
```

I have got this game on python which when the health is lower than 0, it should quit the loop. However, even though I state it so that `done=True` in the if statement, the loop still does not quit although running does become 0. I also checked by printing "aaa", and it does print, but yet done does not equal True in order to quit the loop.

Please help!
**Does it have something to do with the for loop?**

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You need to show the rest of your code. If you're resetting `running` or `done` anywhere it'll cause problems. And yes, unless you manually break out of the `for` loop, that will continue.

Comment: What's wrong with the question. My question does follow all of those criteria.

Comment: @MasaTono: We can't copy your code and run it with no changes.

Comment: @tzaman I thought if I show the whole code, it will be too long.

Comment: You need show the relevant sections -- everywhere you manipulate your loop control variables, at the very least.

Comment: Debug it: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`. The error isn't in the part you are showing us (unless you aren't properly handling the `for level...` loop.

Comment: @tzaman that was all of the manipulation of the loops. The person below answered my question as I did not realise that you had to break the for loop as I thought that if I broke the while loop, the for loop will automatically break.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Well I didn't realise that I had to break out of the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have layers of loops, you need to break out of each one.

done=False

```
while not done:
  for level in range(1,13):
       Code...
       # add "not done" as a condition to get out of this loop:
       while running and not done:
            Code.....

            #10 - Win/Lose check

            if healthvalue<=0:
                done=True
       # break out of the for loop
       if done == True:
         break
```

Comment: I didn't realise that you had to break the for loop. I though if I break the while loop, the for loop will automatically break.

Comment: If that was the case, then there would be no way to continue processing in one of the loops.